# vuejs this.posts.$remove(postId) is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, vuejs2

im trying to remove an array element using $remove. but it says this.posts.$remove is not a function. Can anyone explain where am i wrong?

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" @click="deletePost(post.id)">Xxx</button>
```

vue instance:

```
deletePost(postId){
        console.log(postId);
        this.posts.$remove(postId);
      },
```

this is my example data

[image: my data]

this is my console

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see in the tags that you are using VueJS 2. The `$remove()` method has been deleted: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Array-prototype-remove-removed

As said in the migration guide, you should just use the `splice()` method:

```
methods: {
  removeTodo: function (todo) {
    var index = this.todos.indexOf(todo)
    this.todos.splice(index, 1)
  }
}
```